# How do I fit WP_Query arguments into a function?

Tags: wp-query, functions

How do I add this...

```
'date_query'            => array(
'relation'   => 'OR',
    array(
        'column'  => 'post_date',
        'after'   => '-7 days'
    ),
    array(
        'column'  => 'post_modified',
        'after'   => '-7 days'
    )
)
```

into this...

```
//order home posts by modified
function order_home_asc($query) {
  if ($query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin()) {
    $query->set('orderby', 'modified');
    $query->set('order', 'DESC');
    $query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 889, 738, 1008, 808, 638) );
    $query->set('post_status', 'future,publish');   
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'order_home_asc');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$query->set( 'date_query', array(
    'relation'    => 'OR',
    array(
        'column'  => 'post_date',
        'after'   => '-7 days'
    ),
    array(
        'column'  => 'post_modified',
        'after'   => '-7 days'
    )
) );
```

You might want to adjust the callback's name, since it's not only ordering the home page. You also have `_asc` in that name but are setting the order to DESC within it. So it might cause confusion.

Note that you will not have accessible permalinks for the future posts.

It might be more flexible to filter the posts on the home page according to some category/tag/custom-taxonomy instead of excluding hardcoded post IDs.